# Add class to current page link with jQuery only works for relative but not absolute links

Tags: jquery, css

I am adding a class to the link to the current page using the following code:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
$("ul#inventory-categories a").each( function() {
    var href= $(this).attr("href");
    if (href.length && pathname.indexOf(href) >= 0){
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

This works fine for relative links but not absolute links.

Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: Can you give us examples that are and aren't working?

Comment: Can you add example links that do and do not work?

Comment: You're checking against an entire URL when you're dealing with absolute links. So does your pathname really have 'http://www.example.com' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var pathname = window.location.href;
    $("ul#inventory-categories a").each( function() {
        var href= $(this).attr("href");
        if (href.length && pathname.indexOf(href) >= 0){
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

or...

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var url = window.location.href;
$("ul#inventory-categories a").each( function() {
    var href= $(this).attr("href");
    if (href.length && ((pathname.indexOf(href) >= 0) || ((url.indexOf(href) >= 0) ){
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

(not tested)

Comment: First one did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.pathname` only gives you the path. Perhaps you meant `href.indexOf(pathname)` ?